# Group orderring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking to group a list of projects by a nested field, in this case `custom_field.value` when a certain id is passed in.

```
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "project one ",
  custom_fields: [
       {
           id: 4,
           name: "Year",
           value: "2010"
       },
       {
           id: 5,
           name: "Priority",
           value: "low"
       },
 ]},
 {
  id: 2,
  name: "project two ",
  custom_fields: [
       {
           id: 4,
           name: "Year",
           value: "2011"
       },
       {
           id: 5,
           name: "Priority",
           value: "medium"
       },
 ]},
 {
  id: 3,
  name: "project three ",
  custom_fields: [
       {
           id: 4,
           name: "Year",
           value: "2012"
       },
       {
           id: 5,
           name: "Priority",
           value: "high"
       },
 ]}]
```

So if the `params[:id] == 4` I want the list to be ordered by the custom_field id's corresponding value in decending order.

So in this case they would be ordered.

```
2012
2011
2010
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What have you tried so far? I suggest using `Hash#map (from Enumerable)` followed by `#sort` then `#reverse`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? Your question is a bit unclear but I think this should suffice:

**Your Original Hash**:

```
    test = [{
      id: 1,
      name: "project one ",
      custom_fields: [
           {
               id: 4,
               name: "Year",
               value: "2010"
           },
           {
               id: 5,
               name: "Priority",
               value: "low"
           },
     ]},
     {
      id: 2,
      name: "project two ",
      custom_fields: [
           {
               id: 4,
               name: "Year",
               value: "2011"
           },
           {
               id: 5,
               name: "Priority",
               value: "medium"
           },
     ]},
     {
      id: 3,
      name: "project three ",
      custom_fields: [
           {
               id: 4,
               name: "Year",
               value: "2012"
           },
           {
               id: 5,
               name: "Priority",
               value: "high"
           },
     ]}]
```

**Use `group_by` and `sort`**(with handling for elements where there is no id found):

```
    def group_and_sort(test_hash,id)
      test_hash.group_by do |g| 
        elem = g[:custom_fields].detect {|h| h[:id] == id}
        elem ? elem[:value] : "0"
      end.sort.reverse.to_h
    end
```

Then call like:

```
    group_and_sort(test,4)
    #=>{"2012"=>
      [{:id=>3,
        :name=>"project three ",
        :custom_fields=>
         [{:id=>4, :name=>"Year", :value=>"2012"},
          {:id=>5, :name=>"Priority", :value=>"high"}]}],
     "2011"=>
      [{:id=>2,
        :name=>"project two ",
        :custom_fields=>
         [{:id=>4, :name=>"Year", :value=>"2011"},
          {:id=>5, :name=>"Priority", :value=>"medium"}]}],
     "2010"=>
      [{:id=>1,
        :name=>"project one ",
        :custom_fields=>
         [{:id=>4, :name=>"Year", :value=>"2010"},
          {:id=>5, :name=>"Priority", :value=>"low"}]}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume `projects` is the data you pasted.

```
def order_values_by_id(pjs, id)
  pjs.map{|p| p[:custom_fields].find{|f| f[:id] == id}[:value] }.sort.reverse
end

order_values_by_id(projects)
#=> ["2012", "2011", "2010"]
```

Comment: As a note this will fail if there is no matching `:id` in the custom_fields array because `find` will return `nil`.